# Validate Json String against Model asp.net core api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, form-data, modelstate

I need to send Model data along with Image so I am using `FormData`. As we can't pass model directly, I am using `JSON.stringify`.
How do I validate this Json string against Model (Same as we do `ModelState` validation)?

Comment: Why dont you send the image as blob, and add it to the model so that it gets validated during the ModelState validation?

Comment: @Hozikimaru Is it a better option than `FormData` for large images also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you need to extract the model from the form data first
e.g.

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
var model = new yourViewModel();
model.field1 = request.Form["field1"];
model.field2 = request.Form["field2"];
model.Document = request.Files["Document"];

ModelState.Clear(); 
this.Validate(model); 
if (ModelState.IsValid) {

}
```

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.tryvalidateobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_Validator_TryValidateObject_System_Object_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationContext_System_Collections_Generic_ICollection_System_ComponentModel_DataAnnotations_ValidationResult__System_Boolean_)

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
I am not sure if I can use `ActionFilterAttribute` in this scenario.

Comment: i guess you can check this [post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673649/reading-form-data-in-actionfilterattribute]